# I can't get the edit button working in my address book which is connected to MySQL in java GUI

Tags: java, mysql

I connected the add button to MySQL and it works this EDIT button doesn't and I manually add the ID number instead of autoincrement when I select and edit some and press the edit button nothing happens I think its a simple error in my code plz help me out!

```
private void EditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
       int selectedIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        try {   
            
        
     int ID = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt(selectedIndex, 0).toString());
        String Name =this.name.getText();
        String Mobile =this.mobile.getText();
        String Course =this.course.getText();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/address_book","root","******");
        insert = con1.prepareStatement("update record set where ID= ?, Name= ?,Mobile= ?,Course= ?  ");
         insert.setInt(1,ID);
        insert.setString(2,Name);
        insert.setString(3,Mobile);
        insert.setString(4,Course);
       
        insert.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Updated");
          this.id.setText("");
        this.name.setText("");
        this.mobile.setText("");
        this.course.setText("");
     
       Tabel_update();
       
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
       
    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: `update record set where ` .. set what? [SQL UPDATE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp). Don't silently consume your exceptions, if nothing else at least use `Exception#printStackTrace`

Comment: you need to handle the exception first. which means inside the catch block at least use ex.printstacktrace(); to identify the issue first.

Comment: I did what you told but no erro shows up  hope this what you told me to do :      catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
           
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: The edit button dosent work as i said before

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem code should be like this

```
enter code hereprivate void EditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
   
       

        DefaultTableModel Df = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        int selectedIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        try {  
            
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(Df.getValueAt(selectedIndex, 0).toString());
        String Name =this.name.getText();
        String Mobile =this.mobile.getText();
        String Course =this.course.getText();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/address_book","root","****");
        insert = con1.prepareStatement("update adress_book set Name= ?,Mobile= ?,Course= ? where ID= ?");
        insert.setString(1,Name);
        insert.setString(2,Mobile);
        insert.setString(3,Course);
        insert.setInt(4,ID);
        insert.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Updated");
        this.name.setText("");
        this.mobile.setText("");
        this.course.setText("");
        Tabel_update();
```